# substituting vinegars

Tags: substitutions, vinegar

I have a recipe that calls for Wanjashan naturally brewed organic rice vinegar and I do not have this ingredient.  Is there another vinegar I can used instead?  I have white vinegar, red wine vinegar, and malt vinegar.  The recipe is for sweet and sour pork ribs with honey.

Answer (score 8):

First choice: go out and buy any other rice vinegar - it doesn't have to be that exact brand. Almost any grocery store will have the Marukan brand, for example. Rice vinegar has a somewhat unique, mild taste that there is no exact substitute for. In a pinch, I'd maybe use 80% white vinegar 20% sherry.

Comment: I agree that the best option is some other rice vinegar. I think, though, that if I were substituting I might try malt vinegar and a little sugar, actually. I find rice vinegar to be quite mild in acidity and with some sweetness. But yeah--just get another brand.

Comment: I have often seen recipes that say to use sherry neat if you have no rice vinegar, that certainly seems to be the convention in some of the Chinese cookbooks I have.

Comment: @Orbling - that is the usual substitution for rice wine, not rice vinegar - but it is what made me think to use some of it when making a sub for rice vinegar.

Comment: @Michael Quite right, good idea.  On a tangent, how comes your website is called Herbivoracious, but has non-herbivorous (lacto-ovo) recipes? ;-) [I'm vegan, hence the pedant.]

Comment: @Orbling - for the simple reason that when I chose the name, 3.5 years ago, it didn't occur to me that herbivore would really only include vegans, not lacto-ovo. It is fairly common parlance to refer to any vegetarian as an herbivore. I get this comment occasionally, but it is my "brand" now, too late to change it.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it is common parlance.  People wrongly think of lacto-ovo vegetarians as herbivorous.  It's a good brand and promoting vegetarianism is a good thing, even without fully being vegan.